# How to reconfigure OpenShift-Origin in a Docker container to use localhost as ip

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I started **OpenShift-Server in a docker container**, as described here:
https://docs.openshift.org/latest/getting_started/administrators.html

OpenShift inherits the ip from the docker container: 10.0.2.15

This is a problem, since the OpenShift-Console always redirects to this console on the host. And this ip is not visible from the host.

**Question**: 
How can I make OpenShift use localhost / 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Have you considered using Minishift (https://www.openshift.org/minishift/) instead. It is the easier way of running OpenShift on your local machine.

Comment: Also be aware that the methods of running OpenShift in a container on a local system, or in a VM using Minishift are only really intended for use in local development and not for exposing outside of your machine. For a proper OpenShift installation you should look at using the Ansible based installer.

Comment: Dear Graham. I am learning configuring openSift with the goal to use it in production in the future. So minishift is not suitable for me